# Are simple poles and single poles the same thing?

Tags: complex-analysis

My understanding is that poles have a $\operatorname{ord}(z)<0$, whereas zeros $\operatorname{ord}(z)\ge 0$. Multiple poles have $\operatorname{ord}(z)<-1$ and single poles have $\operatorname{ord}=-1$. I have also heard the term simple pole thrown around. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeros_and_poles) says simple means that $|\operatorname{ord}|=1$ so does simple pole <=> single pole?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.